# R return true or false per row if string contains any of a list of words

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a dataset containing a column of character strings:

```
text <- c('flight cancelled','dog cat','coach travel','car bus','cow sheep',' high bar')
transport <- 0

 df <- data.frame(text,transport)
```

For each row I want to return 1 if the string 'text' contains any of several words or 0 otherwise. My problem is that the only way I can think to do this is using a for loop.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this? My dataset is quite large, so the for loop takes forever to run

```
words<- 'flight|flights|plane|seats|seat|travel|time|coach'

for (i in 1:6){
   df$transport[i] <- ifelse(any(grepl(words,(str_split(as.character(df$text[i]), " ")))) == TRUE,1,0)
 }
```

returns:

```
              text transport
1 flight cancelled         1
2          dog cat         0
3     coach travel         1
4          car bus         0
5        cow sheep         0
6         high bar         0
```

Comment: This is roughly what I would have suggested.  Other than possibly vectorizing it, I can't think of a way to make it faster.

Comment: Maybe use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the dataframe, though I doubt that this would make much if any difference.

Comment: If speed is a concern try `library(data.table); setDT(df)[grepl(words, text), transport := 1L]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is one possibility:

```
df <- data.frame(text =  c('flight cancelled','dog cat','coach travel','car bus','cow sheep',' high bar'), 
                 transport = 0)
words <- 'flight|flights|plane|seats|seat|travel|time|coach'


df[grep(words, df$text, value = F), "transport"] <- 1

              text transport
1 flight cancelled         1
2          dog cat         0
3     coach travel         1
4          car bus         0
5        cow sheep         0
6         high bar         0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well for my purposes.  Just out of curiosity, would there be a simple way to modify this to return 1 if _none_ of the words match?

Comment: you mean 1 if there is no match and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Yeah, so if I have multiple columns based on multiple word lists I can create a column that returns 1 where no matches are present in any other column

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying: but if you have a bunch of columns only containing 0 and 1 and you want additional column which is 1 if all the other columns are zero this can be easily done

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, just realised how easy that is. I'm being an idiot

Answer (score 6):

You can use `words` and `df$text` direct in `grep` to find the lines which you want to set to 1.

```
df$transport[grep(words, df$text)] <- 1
```

Another way is using `grepl` and use `+` to get `0` and `1`:

```
+grepl(words, df$text)
#[1] 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

In case only whole words should be matched they need to be surrounded with `\b` to match boundaries.

```
+grepl(paste0("\\b(", words, ")\\b"), df$text)
#[1] 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Benchmark:

```
bench::mark(
         grepl = +grepl(words, df$text)
       , "grepl\\b" = +grepl(paste0("\\b(", words, ")\\b"), df$text)
       , greplPerl = +grepl(words, df$text, perl = TRUE)
       , stringr = +stringr::str_detect(df$text, words)
       , stringi = +stringi::stri_detect_regex(df$text, words)
       , like = +data.table::like(df$text, words)
       )
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 grepl      10.61µs 11.61µs    62577.        0B     6.26  9999     1    159.8ms
#2 grepl\b    15.29µs 16.31µs    59343.        0B    11.9   9998     2    168.5ms
#3 greplPerl    5.5µs   5.9µs   164148.        0B     0    10000     0     60.9ms
#4 stringr    10.01µs 10.78µs    88661.        0B    17.7   9998     2    112.8ms
#5 stringi     7.48µs  7.93µs   123578.        0B    12.4   9999     1     80.9ms
#6 like       11.83µs 12.66µs    77189.        0B     7.72  9999     1    129.5ms
```

In this case using `grepl` from *base* when setting `perl = TRUE` is the fastest method.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for speed, `stringr` or `stringi` functions usually outperform base functions:

```
library(stringr)

as.integer(str_detect(df$text, words))
[1] 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

EDIT: one more note, consider using word boundaries so that you do not get partial matches (e.g., `flight` matching for the word `flights`)

```
paste0("\\b", gsub("|", "\\b|\\b", words, fixed = T), "\\b") 
[1] "\\bflight\\b|\\bflights\\b|\\bplane\\b|\\bseats\\b|\\bseat\\b|\\btravel\\b|\\btime\\b|\\bcoach\\b"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the apply function:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(any(grepl(words,(str_split(as.character(x["text"]), " ")))) == TRUE,1,0))
```

Comment: There is no need for `apply`, `ifelse`, `any`, `str_split` and `as.character` here. Just `grepl(words, df$text)` as shown by others. Besides the inefficiency `apply` will coerce the `transport` column to `character`.

Comment: Thank you, I had actually tried to use apply but I was getting a bit confused with it, this clears a few things up for me, though it seems the grep method as above works quite a bit faster

Comment: I agree. Apply will be slower.