# How to make my str_detect code more efficient in R?

Tags: r, stringr

I want to check if in my observations (1867) one stock from a list of 6900 names is present, if so to write "yes" in a different column.

This is my code:

```
for (i in 1:length(df$upvotes)){
  if (str_detect(df$text[i], pattern = paste("[:space:](\\$?)",stocks$Stocks,"(\\$?)[:space:]",collapse ="|"))){
    df$call[i] <- "yes"
  }}
```

The problem is that after 20 minutes is still running while my computer heats up a lot. If I remove all of the regex, it finishes the task in a couple of minutes.
How can I improve the code to make it more efficient?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data with `dput(head(df))`? Avoiding loops often make code more efficient.

Comment: it says is too long, and pastebin gives me problems because there are offensive terms in the observations, how can I provide it to you?

Comment: did you use `head` to get only a few lines?

Comment: I copied the code you provided, the problem is that the first observations are entire reddit posts

Comment: OK, I see... What about the other link I suggested?

Comment: I'm trying it now

Comment: difficult to tell without knowing the data you are using.

Comment: If I just replace my variables with those I get this error: 
In grep(stocks$Stocks, df$text, value = F) : argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

------------------------------------------------

df[grep(paste("[:space:]",stocks$Stocks,"[:space:]",collapse ="|"), df$text, value = F), "call"] <- "yes"

------------------------------------
I get this error:
 invalid regular expression '[:space:] AA [:space:]|[:space:] AACG [:space:]|[:space:] AACQ [:space:]|[:space:] AACQU [:space:]| CONTINUES

Comment: I uploaded the df here:
https://we.tl     /t-XqewRzwuae

Comment: did you remove the space between .tl and /t?

Comment: OK I could get it : what is the format, it doesn't look like `csv`?

Comment: Sorry, I had a problem saving it as a csv, I uploaded it as a .rdata file
https://we.tl /t-SoaBp9u3v5 ------- thank you very much for the patience

Comment: OK perfect, could yo also provide `head(dput(stocks))` to have an idea of the words you're looking for?

Comment: class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6935L))
  Stocks
1     AA
2   AACG
3   AACQ
4  AACQU
5  AACQW
6   AAIC

Comment: OK, thanks, see my answer, just edited it to take into account word boundaries

Comment: great! Thank you very much, you are the best! Last question, how can I store the results in the same df of the observation? So if the observation contains a stock name I have a column saying "yes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions provided in [R return true or false per row if string contains any of a list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074127/r-return-true-or-false-per-row-if-string-contains-any-of-a-list-of-words) seems to work with the data you provided.

For example :

```
stocks <- data.frame(stock = c("AAPL","AACG","AACQ","AACQU","AACQW","AAIC"))

stocksearch <- paste0("[\\s$]",stocks$stock,"+[\\s$]",collapse ="|")

which(str_detect(df$text, stocksearch))
[1] 352

df$text[352]
[1] "Blew up my account with AMD and AAPL calls expiring after earnings.\n\nNow I'm going bear mode and hitting up that VIX and spy Puts"

#Dataframe update
df$call[which(str_detect(df$text, stocksearch))] <- "yes"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i tried to add the regex (I would like a space before and after the stock name and a dollar that could either be at the beginning, at the end of the stock name or be absent) to it but I still cannot run it.

My code was: paste("[:space:](\\$?)",stocks$Stocks,"(\\$?)[:space:]",collapse ="|"). I also tried to remove the dollar sign part

Comment: could you give examples of stocks you're looking for. I understand : `$AAPL ` or `AAPL$`. `str_detect("test $AAPL test ",stocksearch)` returns `FALSE`

Comment: Could either be "AAPL", "$AAPL" or "AAPL$"

Comment: I updated the regex according to your needs.